# Can javascript add element to an array without specifiy the key like PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, arrays

In PHP , I can add a value to the array like this:

```
array[]=1;
array[]=2;
```

and the output will be `0=>'1', 1=>'2';`

And if I tried the same code in javascript , it return *Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string* . So , is there any way in JS to work the same as PHP? Thanks

Comment: you can use array.push to Push elements onto an array without specifying the index

Comment: see [this](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_array.asp)

Comment: Oh, you mean if there is a javascript equivalent to PHPs `array_push` ;)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Simply use `Array.push` in javascript

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4];

// append a single value
arr.push(5);  // arr = [1,2,3,4,5]

// append multiple values
arr.push(1,2) // arr = [1,2,3,4,5,1,2]

// append multiple values as array
Array.prototype.push.apply(arr, [3,4,5]); // arr = [1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5]
```

[Array.push on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)

Answer (score 4):

Programmatically, you simply "push" an item in the array:

```
var arr = [];

arr.push("a");
arr.push("b");

arr[0]; // "a";
arr[1]; // "b"
```

You **cannot** do what you're suggesting:

```
arr[] = 1
```

is **not** valid JavaScript.

Comment: PHP array functions and shorthand hacks have absolutely ruined me in javascript.

Answer (score 1):

For special cases You can use next (without .push()):

```
var arr = [];
arr[arr.length] = 'foo';
arr[arr.length] = 'bar';

console.log(arr); // ["foo", "bar"]
```

Answer (score 0):

From [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_push)

```
<script>
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];

function myFunction()
{
fruits.push("Kiwi")
var x=document.getElementById("demo");
x.innerHTML=fruits;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to find a way to add a value as an array element to a variable or property, when such doesn't exist yet. (Much like php's $var[] = 'foo'.) So I asked around, and this is what I learned.

Variable:

```
var arr;
(arr = arr || []).push('foo');
```

Property:

```
var obj = {};
(obj.arr = obj.arr || []).push('foo');
```

|| returns the left side if it's true, and the right side if the left is false. By the time .push() executes, arr is an array--if it wasn't already.